# Does J2ME Media Player on Nokia E65 work?

Tags: java-me, media-player, media, nokia, mmapi

I'm trying to write a simple media playback application in J2ME. Currently I'm starting with the most simple thing, I just want to play a wav file from resources included in the jar file. I'm using this simple code:

```
DataInputStream wav = new DataInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.wav"));
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(wav, "audio/x-wav");
player.addPlayerListener(this);
player.realize();
VolumeControl vc = (VolumeControl) player.getControl("VolumeControl");
if( vc != null )
    vc.setLevel(100);
player.start();
```

I run it on two phones: Nokia E65 with latest firmware and Nokia 3110c with original firmware. On E65 I see that the player is created, it starts playing and there are no exceptions thrown. But I can hear nothing... The same wav file works fine with built in media player.
As you see I have a player listener attached and it only receives single message: `STARTED`. (There is no `VOLUME_CHANGED` or `END_OF_MEDIA` event.)

The same jar file running on Nokia 3110c plays fine and shows all expected player events.

Any idea what may be wrong with the E65 or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've found solution...
http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?p=696514#post696514

Warning Tones must be enabled in user's profile...

Comment: please copy your solution in the answers and accept it to help the future readers of this post to find answers quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution at Nokia forums: [Does J2ME Media Player on Nokia E65 work?](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?191372-Does-J2ME-Media-Player-on-Nokia-E65-work)

Warning Tones must be enabled in user's profile.

> Make sure you have "warning sounds" switched on in the current profile...
>
> ...check the manual for the device. On the N96, it's in Tools, Profiles, (select profile), Options, Personalise, Warning Tones.

There's no way to check this setting from the j2me application code.